# C# send base64 string to php

Tags: c#, php, base64

I am trying to send image data from C# to PHP via a base64 string:

```
try
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
        Textt.Text = "sending data";
        string result = await Task.Run(() => client.UploadString(url, "POST", data));
        //String result1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
        Textt.Text = result;
    }
}
```

I am getting this web exception: "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

I am doing that because I have free PHP hosting with a lot of web space, and my ASP.net MVC app is going to upload files to the PHP host by means of a PHP script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I removed my answer, because I think there must be a better one. If this doesn't generate enough attention in the next week, make a comment with an (@ZacharyKniebel) in it and I'll sponsor a bounty on it.

Comment: with WebClient.UploadFile i can send many bytes as i want. Isn't it possible to make a virtual text document and upload it to php? The point is to send this base64 string to the php, the rest is easy.

Comment: Yes, it is - if you are sending a small amount of data. How big is your image file? Also, sending isn't the problem - it's receiving on the other side.

Comment: about 200KB. But my site will have user upload form so it must work with bigger files too.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty big to simply send in a single burst. Do you know how torrents work?

Comment: no, but i think it wont be so easy

Comment: Okay here's a two liner: First, imagine that there is one seeder and one leecher. Now, what happens is that the large file is broken up into lots of tiny bits and sent to the leecher, whose client reassembles the file, based on the sequence number of each block of data. Essentially, a big file is sent in itty-bitty parts - which is what you need to do.